# Display WMS layer in GWT-Openlayers

Tags: java, gwt, openlayers, wms, gwt-openlayers

I use GWT-Openlayers and i want to add a WMS layer to my Map. Here is the code:

```
    ...
    MapOptions defaultMapOptions = new MapOptions();
    defaultMapOptions.setNumZoomLevels(7);

    //Create a MapWidget
    MapWidget mapWidget = new MapWidget("700px", "700px", defaultMapOptions);

    GoogleV3Options gSatelliteOptions = new GoogleV3Options();
    gSatelliteOptions.setIsBaseLayer(true);
    gSatelliteOptions.setType(GoogleV3MapType.G_SATELLITE_MAP);
    GoogleV3 gSatellite = new GoogleV3("Google Satellite", gSatelliteOptions);

    mapWidget.getMap().addLayer(gSatellite);

    //Create a WMS layer as base layer
    WMSParams wmsParams = new WMSParams();
    wmsParams.setFormat("image/png");
    wmsParams.setLayers("topp:tasmania_state_boundaries");
    wmsParams.setStyles("");
    wmsParams.setParameter("transparent", "true");

    //create a WMS layer
    WMSOptions wmsLayerParams = new WMSOptions();
    wmsLayerParams.setUntiled();
    wmsLayerParams.setTransitionEffect(TransitionEffect.RESIZE);
    wmsLayerParams.setIsBaseLayer(false);

    String wmsUrl = "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms";

    final WMS wmsLayer = new WMS("Basic WMS", wmsUrl, wmsParams,
                                 wmsLayerParams);

    //Add the WMS to the map
    Map map = mapWidget.getMap();
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);

    //Lets add some default controls to the map
    map.addControl(new LayerSwitcher()); //+ sign in the upperright corner to display the layer switcher
    map.addControl(new OverviewMap()); //+ sign in the lowerright to display the overviewmap
    map.addControl(new ScaleLine()); //Display the scaleline
    map.addControl(new MousePosition()); 

    //Center and zoom to a location
    LonLat lonLat = new LonLat(146.7, -41.8);
    lonLat.transform(new Projection(ProjectionCode.LONGLAT.getEpsgCode()).getProjectionCode(),
            map.getProjection()); //transform lonlat to OSM coordinate system
    map.setCenter(lonLat, 6);
    ...
```

I used the example codes i found on this site: 
http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html

Anyone can try out because the wmsUrl points to the demo site.

The problem is that the WMS layer only appears when i zoom out to the outermost zoom level. Than if i try to zoom in, it disappears again. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found a setting:

```
wmsLayerParams.setDisplayOutsideMaxExtent(true);
```

But i don't understand why isn't the true value the default...

Comment: I'm facing the issue, when i set up both  wmsLayerParams.setIsBaseLayer(true);
        wmsLayerParams.setDisplayOutsideMaxExtent(true);
 i don't see the tasmania border layer at all, even if I explicitly select the needed wms base layer. but as non-base layer it is correctly shown

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not set the zoom levels correctly. Your zoom level ranges from 6-7 only. You have defined max. zoom as 7. `defaultMapOptions.setNumZoomLevels(7);` and centered the map at zoom level 6. `map.setCenter(lonLat, 6);` So map is only showing between zoom levels 6 and 7.
Increasing `setNumZoomLevels` to higher value might help.